# receive Directory from NAS with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, xcode8, nsurlsession, nas

i´m new to NSURLSession and i want connect to my local NAS Server with this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2/"];
    NSString * user = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"admin"];
    NSString * password = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"xxx"];
    NSURLProtectionSpace * protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:url.host port:[url.port integerValue] protocol:url.scheme realm:nil authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

    NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential
                             credentialWithUser:user
                             password:password
                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    NSURLCredentialStorage * cred_storage ;
    [cred_storage setCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.URLCredentialStorage = cred_storage;
    sessionConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSLog(@"viewdidload");

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url];
    [task resume];
```

my request returns a status code 200 and in my delegate method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"didReceiveData:%@", dataString);

}
```

i get this log:

didReceiveData:

> Index_Page
>
> var queryArg = location.search;
>   
>     if (queryArg.substring(1,5) == "url=") {
>
> ```
>   var hiddenURL = queryArg.substring(5,queryArg.length);
> ```
>
> }
>   
>     else if (queryArg.substring(1,7) == "mount=" ) {
>
> ```
>   var hiddenURL = queryArg.substring(7,queryArg.length);
> ```
>
> }
>   
>     else {
>
> ```
>   var hiddenURL = "";
> ```
>
> }
>   
>   
>   
>     if (hiddenURL == "") {
>
> ```
>   var seperateHref = window.location.href.split("/");
>
>   if (seperateHref[0] == "https:")
>
>       window.location =
> ```
>
> "https://"+seperateHref[2]+"/"+seperateHref[3]+"/desktop,/login.html";
>
> ```
>   else
>
>       window.location =
> ```
>
> "http://"+seperateHref[2]+"/"+seperateHref[3]+"/desktop,/login.html";
>   
>     }
>   
>     else {
>
> ```
>   location.replace("/desktop,/login.html"+queryArg);
> ```
>
> }

why won´t my code authenticate with the NAS even when i passed user and pw?
after i tried a bit, with no credential in my code, the didReceiveChallenge - delegateMethod never gets called too. i just want to receive the directories to fill up my tableview to create a simple file browser..

Comment: Are you saying that it returns a 200 status code even if you don't authenticate?  That's a bug.  It should send 401.

Comment: yes, NSHTTPURLResponse.statusCode = 200

Comment: Chances are you can't fix this without using a third-party URL loading library like libcurl. NSURLSession et al don't even attempt authentication unless they get a 401 at least once, IIRC.

Comment: thank you so far.. i will check out this libcurl